# Delete attributes collected by ohai plugin

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I have been using the [ohai-softlayer cookbook](https://github.com/coderanger/ohai-softlayer) for fetching the softlayer metadata. As part of collecting the softlayer metadata it collects the     [user_metadata attribute](https://github.com/coderanger/ohai-softlayer/blob/master/files/default/plugins/softlayer.rb#L39)   for the softlayer VM. Somehow I dont want user_metadata to be pushed to the chef-server, so I used another cookbook [blacklist_node_attrs](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/blacklist_node_attrs) . 
I have another cook book which includes these 2 in its default recipe.

```
include_recipe 'blacklist_node_attrs'
include_recipe 'ohai-softlayer::default'
```

In the attributes folder I have this piece of code which adds the blacklist attribute name.

```
node.default[:blacklist] = {
 "softlayer" => {
  'user_metadata' => true
  }
}
```

I have included these cookbooks at the last in the run_list.
When I run the command

```
knife node show <nodename> -a softlayer
```

It displayes the user_metadata attribute. Do you know how can I restrict it from getting displayed ? How can I delete the attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the version of the cookbook was not updated. I changed the version of wrapper cookbook (Refer in question ->  I have another cook book which includes these 2 in its default recipe. ) and then the changes were reflected on chef node.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also have the `depends` line in your cookbook's metadata for each of those. Also make sure you've run `chef-client` at least once successfully.

Comment: Yes I have 
depends          'ohai-softlayer'
depends          'blacklist_node_attrs' in the cookbooks metadata.rb. 
I did not get what do you mean by running chef-client successfully

Comment: I run the chef-client manually and then knife node show <node_name> -a softlayer does not show any attribute. Earlier it was listing softlayer metadata collected from ohai-softlayer plugin

Comment: The node data on the Chef server is only updated when chef-client runs without errors, and only after the run finishes.

Comment: The chef-client was successful in my case. No errors. And then it doesnt show the softlayer group data. What might be reason ?